# are bootstrap and html5 conflicting?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use both HTML5 semantic markup and bootstrap to make a page that is easily indexed by search engines and mobile responsive.  I am using the "body" tag as the bootstrap container which makes HTML5 tags like "main", "header" and "footer" all bootstrap "rows".

```
    <body class="container">
      <header class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <nav class="row">
          </nav> 
        </div>
      </header> 
      <main class="row">
        <section class="col-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
            </div>  
          </div>
        </section>
      </main>
    </body>
```

By doing this each HTML5 semantic tag ends up requiring 1 or more additional html tags between itself and the actual content to comply with the bootstrap spec.

> In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of rows.

Shouldn't a "section" be a "row" and not a "col-12" because it will always be the full width of the screen regardless of the device?

Do all of these extra divs have an negative impact on how a site is indexed?

Would it have a negative impact on how a site is indexed or the responsive layout to make rows "grandchildren" of the container and cols "grandchildren" of rows?

Comment: `main` does not have to be a `row`. You could nest your rows inside the sections if you want.

Comment: @Marco so rows don't have to be immediate children of a container?

Comment: Everything that has children is a container. So rows will always be a child of a container. Main, section, article, header and footer are just semantic markup. You can decorate them with classes if you want to, but you do not have to. They exist, so algorithms have an easier time deciding what is content and what not.